"ROC AUC reflects the likelihood that a random positive instance will be located to the right of a random negative instance". How come?
According to this webpage,

ROC AUC reflects the likelihood that a random positive (red) instance will be located to the right of a random negative (gray) instance.


Would you please explain this statement, both in plain language as well as mathematically?
